# Place a geometry at any place on the map (Mapbox GL)

Tags: mapbox

I have a predefined house geometry, let's say it's a square with a side of 6 meters.

And I want to place it anywhere on the map with a mouse click. I tried to draw this square near [0,0] coordinates and use turf transformTranslate to move it to desired coordinates. But the geometry of the building is distorted. Turned from a square to a parallelogram.

Now I am thinking of drawing the building with xy coordinates and using map.unproject to get the lat/lng coordinates. But maybe there is an easy way to do this?

```
 const poly = { "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "coordinates": [ [ [ 6.638501146414939, 0.10866818535053824 ], [ 6.638501146414939, 0.10860431560567463 ], [ 6.6385632993425645, 0.10860431560567463 ], [ 6.6385632993425645, 0.10866818535053824 ], [ 6.638501146414939, 0.10866818535053824 ] ] ], "type": "Polygon" } }

            const center = map.getCenter().toArray()
            const from = turf.centerOfMass(poly);
            const to = turf.point(center);
            const options = { units: 'kilometers' };
            const distance = turf.rhumbDistance(from, to, options);
            const bearing = turf.rhumbBearing(from, to);
            const newPoly = turf.transformTranslate(poly, distance, bearing);
            map.getSource("maine").setData((newPoly))
```

Comment: You could use `turf.circle` to create circle of desired size at desired location and then `turf.bbox` to get square.